# Morphism from a scheme to the spectrum of global section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

This is exercise II.2.4 in Hatshorne:

> Let $A$ be a ring and $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ a scheme. We have the associated map of sheaves $f^\#: \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec } A} \rightarrow f_* \mathcal{O}_X$. Taking global sections  we obtain a homomorphism $A \rightarrow \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. Thus there is a natural map $\alpha : \text{Hom}(X,\text{Spec} A) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$. Show $\alpha$ is bijective.

We can find a map $\beta: \text{Hom}(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(X,\text{Spec} A)$ by sending a map $g: A \rightarrow \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ to a map from $X$ to $\text{Spec} A$ defined as follows:

First taking affine open cover of $X = \cup \, \text{Spec} A_i$, then taking spectrum of the map $g$ (after being composed with the restriction map, i.e. consider $g_i: A \rightarrow A_i$ and take $\text{Spec} g_i$), and glue them together. Details are in the post: [Prove that the natural map $\alpha : \text{Hom}(X,\text{Spec} A) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$ is an isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523392/prove-that-the-natural-map-alpha-texthomx-textspec-a-rightarrow-te?rq=1).

**My question is**: How to show the map $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are inverse to each other?

The question in affine case is casual, where $\alpha$ is simply "taking global sections" and $\beta$ is "taking spectrum". These two are "inverse" to each other indeed. Yet how to show this in the general case on **scheme (not just affine schemes)**. In other word, the adjunction of $\Gamma$ and $\text{Spec}$ is in affine case, hence is "local". Yet how to "glue these adjunctions"?

Any direct proof on "the map $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are inverse to each other" is welcomed :)

P.S. I know that there is a proof in broader context on locally ringed space, i.e. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I1, but I still hope to practice the method of gluing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:X\to\text{Spec}A$ be a morphism of schemes. Then there is an associated homomorphism of sheaves $f^\#:\mathscr O_\text{Spec A}\to f_*\mathscr O_X$, and taking  global sections gives $\alpha(f):A\to\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X)$. Now, let $X=\cup\text{Spec}A_i$ be an open affine cover. $\beta\circ\alpha(f)$ is obtained by glueing the morphisms $\text{Spec}A_i\to\text{Spec}A$. However, these morphisms *are* just $f|_{\text{Spec}A_i}$, so glueing them just gives $f$.

Conversely, let $g:A\to\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X)$ be a ring homomorphism and let $X=\cup\text{Spec}A_i$. Then, $\beta(g)$ is obtained by glueing together the morphisms of schemes $f_i:\text{Spec}A_i\to\text{Spec}A$. This gives a morphism of sheaves $\beta(g)^\#:\mathscr O_{\text{Spec}A}\to(\beta(g))_*\mathscr O_X$.

Let $a\in A$, so that $g(a)\in\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X)$. We want to show $g(a)=(\alpha\circ\beta(g))(a)$. It is enough to show that $g(a)|_{\text{Spec}A_i}=(\alpha\circ\beta(g))(a)|_{\text{Spec}A_i}$. $$
(\alpha\circ\beta(g))(a)|_{\text{Spec}A_i}
=(\beta(g)^\#(X))(a)|_{\text
{Spec}A_i}
=(f_i^\#(\text{Spec}A))(a)=g(a)|_{\text{Spec}A_i}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer again! But I'm a bit confused at some points. Firstly, on the last line of your answer, you wrote $(\alpha\circ\beta(g))(a)|_{\text{Spec}A_i}
=(\beta(g)^\#(X))(a)|_{\text
{Spec}A_i}$. Yet I think $\beta(g)^\#(X)$ should be replaced by $\beta(g)^\#(\text{Spec}(A))$, since the morphism $\beta(g)^\#$ is defined on the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{(\text{Spec} A)}$ and taking global section using $\alpha$ should leads to $\beta(g)^\#(\text{Spec}(A))$ instead of $\beta(g)^\#(X)$.

Comment: And when checking $\beta \circ \alpha = \text{id}$ in the first paragraph, I find it hard to verify that "the morphisms *are* just $f \vert_{\text{Spec} A_i}$". I tried to explicitly write the morphisms $\text{Spec} A_i \rightarrow \text{Spec} A$ as $\text{Spec} (\text{res}_{\text{Spec} A_i}^X \circ \alpha(f) )$, but how can I see that this is just  $f \vert_{\text{Spec} A_i}$. I feel that the naturality of sheaf morphisms may be needed, yet I find it hard to fill in the details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer, and sincerely sorry for the late reply!