# Detail in showing that the natural map $\alpha : \text{Hom}(X,\text{Spec} A) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$ is an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

In this answer below ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1526426/86425)), **Why is it enough to show that $f_i|_{V_{ijk}}=f_j|_{V_{ijk}}$?**

> Show that the natural map $\alpha : \text{Hom}_{\operatorname{Sch}}(X,\text{Spec} A) \rightarrow \text{Hom}_{\operatorname{Ring}}(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$ is an isomorphism.

> Let $g\in\hom_{ring}(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

> Cover $X$ by affine open subsets $\{U_i=Spec(A_i)\}_{i\in I}$.

> Now, the inclusion $U_i\hookrightarrow X$ gives us a map from global section of $U_i$ to global section of $X$ (i.e.,  $\rho^{X}_{Spec(A_i)}:\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow A_i$)

> We take the composite map $A\hookrightarrow\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\hookrightarrow A_i$

> This gives rise to a map from $f_i:U_i=Spec(A_i)\rightarrow Spec(A)$ for each $i\in I$ (Note, $f_i$ is nothing but the Spec map of the composition of $g$ with the restriction map $\rho^{X}_{U_i}$, i.e., $f_i=Spec(\rho^{X}_{U_i}\circ g)$)

> Notation: If $h:A\rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism, then the corresponding scheme morphism is denoted by $Spec(h):Spec(B)\rightarrow Spec(A)$

> Now, we use that fact- If $X$ and $Y$ are two schemes, then giving a morphism from $X$ to $Y$ is equivalent to giving an open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of X, together with morphism $f_i:U_i\rightarrow Y$, where $U_i$ has the induced open subscheme structure, such that the restrictions of $f_i$  and $f_j$ to $U_i\cap U_j$ are the same, for each $i,j\in I$

> Therefore, we need to check:
> $$
> f_i|_{U_i\cap U_j}=f_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}
> $$
> We need to cover $U_i\cap U_j$, again by affine open subsets (Otherwise, we cannot use the functoriality of $Spec$) Cover $U_i\cap U_j$ by $\{V_{ijk}=Spec(B_{ijk})\}_{k\in I}$

> Enough to show,
> $f_i|_{V_{ijk}}=f_j|_{V_{ijk}}$ .

---

---

**Why is it enough to show that $f_i|_{V_{ijk}}=f_j|_{V_{ijk}}$?**

It seems circular to me. If we are taking another cover, we would have to show that the maps agree on pairwise intersections of this cover then.

Comment: I don't understand why you took out [the link to the answer you copied this from](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1526426/). But the answer to your question is the gluing lemma: given morphisms on each element of an open cover that agree on overlaps, there is a unique morphism which restricts to each of these. There's no suggestion of circularity there.

Comment: @KReiser We covered $U_i \cap U_j$ by $\{V_{ijk}\}$ and we showed that $f_i|_{V_{ijk}}=f_j|_{V_{ijk}}$. But don't we now need to show that $f_i$ and $f_j$ agree on pairwise overlaps of the cover $\{V_{ijk}\}$?

Comment: Do you concur that if two maps agree on some open set $W$, then for any open subset $W'\subset W$, those two maps will again agree when restricted to $W'$?

Comment: @KReiser Ah, yes. I see now. I guess an obvious result is that: If $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a cover of $X$, and we have maps $f, g$ on $X$ such that $f|_{U_i}=g|_{U_i}$ for all $i \in I$, then $f = g$.