Glueing of morphism between schemes
On page 70 of Wedhorn& Görtz's Algebraic Geometry I:Schemes, there is one result which I do not know how to prove.

Let $X,Y$ be schemes and let $X=\cup_i U_i$ be an open covering. Then morphisms $f_i:U_i\rightarrow Y$ glue to a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ if and only if they agree on intersections.

I do not know how to show '$\Leftarrow$'. That is, we need to construct the natural transformation $f^{-1}\mathscr O_Y\rightarrow \mathscr O_X$
What I think is for each $U\subset X$ open we need to use the exact sequence we get from the sheaf axiom of $\mathscr O_X$ applied to the open cover $U=\cup _i U\cap U_i$ and try to construct a map $f^{-1}\mathscr O_Y(U)\rightarrow \Pi \mathscr O_X(U_i)$ which vanishes if we further compose $\Pi f^{-1} \mathscr O_Y\rightarrow \Pi  \mathscr O_X(U\cap U_i\cap U_j)$ then by the universal property of limit we have a unique map $f^{-1}\mathscr O_Y(U)\rightarrow \mathscr O_X(U)$ and we need to argue this induced map is also natural. But I do not know how to do. Any help is appreciated.

For gluing the underlying morphisms of sheaves, read the answers in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/442911/190421.

Why use inverse image sheaf? Surely that makes things more complicated..
